# How to handle high volume of messages in spring message listener

Tags: message, middleware

What are the best ways to handle high volume(3.2 million messages) in 1 hour through spring message listener. How do we handle the exceptions while listening the messages ?, How do we write into database during this time ?

Comment: **How do we write in to database during this time?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html

This concept is especially useful in web applications where it's impossible to handle a complex task during a short HTTP request window.
It should work well with a large volume of messages.

Comment: Thanks, It addresses volume using worker queue, but how about writing in to database, we cannot have one write for each of 3.2 million messages. How do we manage writing in to database at such volume ?

Comment: Read about this project more. You can have queue, than process messages. Similar to task scheduler in Spring.